# How can I fix my WiFi on Ubuntu 12.10?

Tags: 12.10, wireless

I am new to Ubuntu. I had installed Ubuntu 12.10 on my laptop HP Compaq Presario C707tu  for the first time.  But my Wireless is not working as it is not detecting the available networks. I am able to connect through wire.

On the other hand WiFi is working properly on Windows 7.

Comment: The correct answer depends on your exact wireless device. Please edit your question to add the details of your wireless card learned from this terminal command: lspci -nn

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
sudo rmmod iwlwifi
```

and

```
sudo modprobe iwlwifi bt_coex_active=0
```

**Startup script:**

If the above works you can create a startup script so that it will work when you reboot:

```
sudo gedit /etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf
```

and add this line:

```
options iwlwifi bt_coex_active=N
```

sudo su
echo iwlwifi >> /etc/modules
exit

Answer (score 0):

You should try to install drivers using the "additional drivers" section of the "software sources" settings item.

To run it, you can search for "software sources" in Unity, or run "software-properties-gtk" (without quotes) in a terminal and select the "Additional Drivers" tab.